# Light text editor for CSV file?

Tags: windows, text-editors, csv

Could anybody suggest a light (small, fast) text editor that can

- handle columnar view of csv files?
- save quote character to all fields, even if not 'necessary'

OpenOffice Calc is bit big for my old laptop. My favourite Notepad++ cannot present a columnar view. And it seems to me that [Sharp Tools Spreadsheet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sharptools/) cannot import CSV files. Google Docs converts some date fields by default, which I do not want and it is really slow.

Comment: CSVed is really good choice. I recommend it to anybody ... just enjoy.

Comment: if somebody is looking ***only for a csv viewer***, [TadViewer](https://www.tadviewer.com/) is a fairly new one: quite light to open (much lighter than LibreOffice for sure), and with a modern interface, though not exactly small at ~48MB

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/) - at 1MB it seems pretty light.

[image]

Note that as of version 2.2.1 it has trouble opening large CSV files.

- a 4,000,000 row, 313 column, LF terminated CSV simply gives a "File is empty" warning

  - reduced to ~1000 rows it opens, but drops columns 227 - 313
  - reduced to 1 row, it still drops columns 227 - 313

Comment: exactly what I wanted :-) Thank you for that.

Comment: I'm trying CSVed 2.3.0 (and its little brother uniCSVed 1.1) and unfortunately they don't support **line breaks** into text wrapped by double-quotes, wich is a kind of [CSV standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2) (_6. Fields containing line breaks..._)

Comment: Super prog. The only thing I cannot find, how to force it to see the first line as column names?

Comment: Cannot escape double quotes, e.g. `"` -> `""` or `\"`

Comment: appreciate, but it seems it has problem with opening UTF-8 file

Comment: version 2.5 opens 300MB files with utmost ease!

Answer (score 6):

I have written a product called **[Ron's Editor](http://www.ronsplace.eu/Products/RonsEditor)** which you might want to look at. I am always interested in making it more useful/powerful so I would be interested in your feedback.

> Ron's Editor is a powerful CSV file editor. It can open any format of
>   separated text, including the standard comma and tab separated files
>   (CSV and TSV), and allows total control over their content and
>   structure.
>
> With a clean and neat interface Ron's Editor is also ideal to simply
>   view and read CSV, or any text delimited, files.
>
> Ron's Editor is the ultimate CSV editor, whether you need to edit a
>   CSV file, clean some data, or merge and convert to another format,
>   this is the ideal solution for anyone who regularly works with CSV
>   files.

[image: Ron's Editor]

Comment: As long as your prog does not offer any unique functionality compared with the free alternatives (like CSVed), you might consider making it more affordable or even free for personal use. Now it looks like you are trying to "sell air".

Comment: @Ilya , maybe I don't know how to use CSVed, but I actually found this Ron's Editor much better than CSVed. CSVed doesn't seem to display column names correctly and you can't edit the cells in place but instead it opens a popup window. In Ron's Editor both of those things work.

Comment: Can confirm, anyone who has used both programs extensively will easily undertand the superiority of Ron's Editor.

Answer (score 4):

[CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/) is a light weight editor specifically designed for editing CSV files on Windows. It's free.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Windows port of emacs and then [use the CSV mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CsvMode).