# Looking for a very fast to load lightweight csv viewer

Tags: software-rec, openoffice, csv, viewer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [light text editor for csv file? (on windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/119655/light-text-editor-for-csv-file-on-windows)

I frequently need to open csv files just to have a look at what is inside and what its structure is. I also may need to find a text string and possibly edit a typographical error.

I can do this in excel or openoffice calc. I am looking for something that is almost instantaneous. Notepad would work if only it layed it out in columns. Openoffice calc always asks me what I want to separate by and guesses correctly but I do not know how to make it go ahead without making me deal with a dialog box.

Can you suggest a way to make openoffice faster or better yet direct me to a Windows program that is as lightweight as notepad but actually separates the fields into columns.

Comment: Here's an online tool: http://www.sharecsv.com/

Comment: [TadViewer](https://www.tadviewer.com/) is a fairly new one, not exactly tiny (~48MB), but quite light to open (much lighter than LibreOffice for sure), and with a modern interface.

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer. It is [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/)

I have been using CSVed for about 10 minutes. It is fast and way more powered than I could have imagined. In fact, as a data manager of a single table it is absolutely fantastic and fast. In fact spreadsheet and database programs look downright clumsy compared to CSVed. Those other programs are good when one is caculating numbers or doing lookups or running a relational database where there are multiple tables and dependent queries. However, often I and other people are really just using one flat table at a time to manage some information. CSVed is amazing.

I did have one problem however which I have not fully explored. When I used the export wizard window, I could not get the wizard window to close and had to use ctrl-alt-delete to end the application.

There is a similar question at [Light text editor for CSV file?](https://superuser.com/questions/119655/light-text-editor-for-csv-file-on-windows).

Comment: +1 for mentioning a duplicate of your own question.