# Lightweight CSV viewer for Mac?

Tags: mac, development, csv

I need to view (large) CSV files on my Mac. I could use something like OpenOffice, but unfortunately it's pretty big and slow. I'm wondering if there's a Mac equivalent of some of the  Windows tools mentioned [on this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/119655/light-text-editor-for-csv-file-on-windows).

Comment: Adding on my own remark about the slowness of OpenOffice: the new LibreOffice is a *lot* faster in starting up than the old Oracle version. Still a bit heavy for just viewing CSV files though.

Answer (score 56):

Quick Look the file.  There are two methods of doing so.

1. Right click the file, in the context menu, select 'Quick Look "file you right-clicked"'.
2. Click the file, keyboard shortcut Command-Y.

Comment: Probably the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: also you can select the file and press "spacebar"

Comment: Too slow on the latest MBP for CSV files even over a few MB...

Comment: This is cool and all, but you can't even select data to copy/paste.

Comment: And quicklook doesn't align the columns, so it's difficult to visually scan as a table.

Answer (score 18):

**Update 7/24/2019**

Commenter @Boris Yakubchik points out there's a new CSV app: Tablecruncher - [tablecruncher.com](http://tablecruncher.com) . I have not tested it.

**Update 4/13/2017**

There's a new desktop app for viewing and analyzing CSV files on macOS: [Tad](http://tadviewer.com/).

**Update 9/8/2016**

There's a new cross-platform desktop app for viewing CSV files: [Comma Chameleon](http://comma-chameleon.io/).

**Original answer**

[Open Refine](http://openrefine.org) weighs in at 50.6 MB, but I don't think that's the 'weight' you're interested in. Anyway I think it's a good tool for any size dataset. They make it faster by paginating the data.

Comment: This is the BEST tool to edit/refine/reformat CSV files. Period.

Comment: Very good indeed, but that's not what we can call lightweight

Comment: Google Refine is now archived. Can you suggest alternatives?

Comment: @Manu Google no longer maintains Refine, but it's still available as an open source project: http://openrefine.org

Comment: Chokes on a 2GB file.

Comment: Doesn't work well. Not intuitive design at all. Very slow.

Comment: I tried Comma Chameleon on OS X 10.11 and wasn't impressed. It was buggy (popping up errors every time I resize) and can't reorder columns or search for text, so it didn't meet my needs

Comment: Also tried Comma Chameleon, it was actually very slow (slower than MS Excel).

Comment: Refine chokes on a 5 MB file. Comma Chameleon and Tad work well. Tad has much more features.

Comment: A new super-fast CSV viewer (and editor) is Tablecruncher - https://tablecruncher.com/ ... it can handle files > 2GB

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how light-weight it is, but I found this with a quick Google search: [XTabulator 2](http://www.bartastechnologies.com/products/xtabulator/)

> XTabulator is a tabular data file editor for Mac OS X. With XTabulator, you can edit, manipulate, > massage, slice, and dice comma-separated (CSV), tab-separated (TAB), or anything-separated files quickly and easily.

Comment: A note for others: Free version adds a line "Created by XTabulator" in every CSV you edit with it.